# paintComponent doesnot show anything

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

[image]I am building a program that shows the temperature for the given place(See the screenshot) I want to display the result in displayPanal(JPanal). I placed the paint component in the extended class of displayPanel. But it doesnot show anything. I just tried to display a "Hello" with g.drawString method to test but it doesnot show anything. So I am stuck to proceed further.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}//main

private static void createAndShowGUI(){
    GridLayout panelLayout = new GridLayout(3,0);
    panelLayout.setHgap(10);
    panelLayout.setVgap(10);
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(panelLayout);

    //location label
    JLabel locationLabel = new JLabel("Location");
    panel.add(locationLabel);
    //text Field for location
    final JTextField locationText = new JTextField();
    panel.add(locationText);
    //month label
    JLabel monthLabel = new JLabel("Month of the Year");
    panel.add(monthLabel);
    //comboBox for months
    String[] months = new String[] {"","January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    JComboBox<String> monthList = new JComboBox<>(months);
    panel.add(monthList);
    //JCheckBox
    JCheckBox celsiusCheck = new JCheckBox("Show Celsius Temperature");
    panel.add(celsiusCheck);

    //Button inside button pane
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 150, 0, 0));
    JButton goButton = new JButton("Go");
    buttonPane.add(goButton);

    //JPanel for display
    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
    displayPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));


    //Create and setup window
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Midterm Project");
    frame.setSize(500, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    mainPanel.add( panel );
    mainPanel.add( buttonPane );
    mainPanel.add( displayPanel );

    //Set up the content pane.
    mainPanel.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


}//createAndShowGUI()

class displayPanel extends JPanel {
    double fahrenheit = generateRand();
    //double celsius = getCelsius(fahrenheit);
    String celsius = Double.toString(getCelsius(fahrenheit));
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);
    }//paintComponent(); 
}
```

Comment: Tom you are building "an program"? are you from checkslovakia then??

Comment: `displayPanel` should be called `DisplayPanel` and it should override `getPreferredSize()` to return a logical size for this component. `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); *paint BG */
 g.drawString("Hello", 10, 10);`

Comment: Question closed as a duplicate because in your previous question you were given a link to the Swing tutorial that shows how custom painting is done. The code you posted does NOT look like the demo code. You were given a link to the tutorial for a reason. To give you skeleton code to follow. All you need to do is change the painting code. Learn from working code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
```

Should be...

```
  JPanel displayPanelVar = new displayPanel();
```

From the looks of it!

displayPanel was changed to displayPanelVar because the variable name cannot be the same as the class, may be worthwhile renaming the displayPanel class name to DisplayPanel

Comment: But still getting error and i am not able to do that.
"No enclosing instance of type MidyermProjectTest2 is accessible

Comment: @Tom You've just described an entirely different problem which isn't related to the code snippet you've provided